# Extract values by property type

Tags: typescript

In the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Wrapper%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WrapperOpt%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3F%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a1%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a2%3A%20Wrapper%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a3%3A%20WrapperOpt%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b1%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b2%3F%3A%20Wrapper%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b3%3F%3A%20WrapperOpt%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Wrapped%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20A%5D%3A%20A%5Bkey%5D%20extends%20Wrapper%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20WrappedOpt%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20A%5D%3A%20A%5Bkey%5D%20extends%20WrapperOpt%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%20%7D%3B) I want to filter properties by type:

```
interface Wrapper<T> {
    x: T;
}

interface WrapperOpt<T> {
    y?: T;
}

interface A {
    a1: number;
    a2: Wrapper<number>;
    a3: WrapperOpt<number>;

    b1?: string;
    b2?: Wrapper<string>;
    b3?: WrapperOpt<string>;
}

type Wrapped = { [key in keyof A]: A[key] extends Wrapper<infer T> ? T : never };
type WrappedOpt = { [key in keyof A]: A[key] extends WrapperOpt<infer T> ? T : never };
```

It works with type `Wrapper` giving me `Wrapped` where only `a2` and `b2` are not `never`:

```
type Wrapped = {
    a1: never;
    a2: number;
    a3: never;
    b1?: never;
    b2?: string;
    b3?: never;
}
```

But it does not work with `WrapperOpt` giving me `WrappedOpt`:

```
type WrappedOpt = {
    a1: {};
    a2: {};
    a3: {};
    b1?: {};
    b2?: {};
    b3?: {};
}
```

But I expect it to have `a3` and `b3` with correct types and all other with never:

```
type Wrapped = {
    a1: never;
    a2: never;
    a3: number;
    b1?: never;
    b2?: never;
    b3?: string;
}
```

How can I fix it?

By the way, in future I'm going to get rid of `never` in types according to [this description](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199) and get clean:

```
type Wrapped = {
    a2: number;
    b2?: string;
}

type WrappedOpt = {
    a3: number;
    b3?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: when checking `extends` left type have to be wrapped into `Required`:

```
type WrappedOpt = { [key in keyof A]: Required<A[key]> extends WrapperOpt<infer T> ? T : never };
```